# Reading bytes from Arduino Uno

Tags: java, arduino, rxtx, serial-communication, arduino-uno

I'm using the RxTx library for communication between Arduino and Java app. My Arduino cod is:

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("Hello world");
  delay(1000);
}
```

If you want to see all my java cods [All](https://github.com/iqnev/JavaRxtx/tree/master/src/testcomunication). I have a method for read bytes from arduino

```
public byte[] readBlocked(int num) throws IOException {
        byte[] buff;
        buff = new byte[num];

       this.inputStream.readFully(buff, 0, num);

        return buff;
    }
```

In TestComunication class i print receive data

```
public class TestComunication {

    private Connection connection;
    //private CommPortIdentifier port;
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = {
        "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
        "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
        "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
        "COM3", // Windows
        "/dev/tty.usbmodem621",
        "/dev/tty.usbmodem411"
    };

    public TestComunication() throws IOException {

        SerialClassConnection serialClassConnection = null;
        CommPortIdentifier port = null;

        serialClassConnection = SerialClassConnection.getInstance();
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    port = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (port == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(port.getName());

        serialClassConnection.openPort(port);

        this.connection = serialClassConnection;

        this.manageData(this.connection);
    }

    private void manageData(Connection conn) throws IOException {

        Connection connection;
        int availableBytes;
        byte[] inBytes;

        connection = conn;
        // listen forever for incoming data

        while (true) {
            if (connection.isDataAvailable()) {

                inBytes = connection.readBlocked(11);
                String text = new String(inBytes, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(text);
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        new TestComunication();
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");

    }
}
```

I am sending string

> Hello world

from Arduino Uno. In my Java app i' m reading this string as bytes. But i'm receiving choppy data.  Example:

```
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7
/dev/tty.usbmodem621
Held
Hello
world
Hel
lo world
H
ello world
```

The main problem: The string `Hello World` convert to ASCII is

> 072 101 108 108 111 032 119 111 114 108 100

but i don't receive that sequence every time. Example i receive:

> 072 108 101 108 111 032 119 111 114 108 100
>
> 101 072 108 108 111 032  111 114 108 119 100
>
> 101 072 108 111 032  114 108 111 119 100 108

But length of receive data is correct 11 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm what return `this.inputStream.readFully(buff, 0, num);`
check this method, maybe it's wrong

Comment: This method return 11 bytes but different